# Purge command keeps getting ratelimited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey so i made this purge command and it keeps getting ratelimited.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(self,ctx, limit: int):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
        purge_embed = discord.Embed(title='Purge [;purge]',
                                    description=f'Successfully purged {limit} messages. \n Command executed by {ctx.author}.',
                                    color=discord.Colour.random())
        purge_embed.set_footer(text=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=purge_embed)
```

This is the error:

`WARNING:discord.http:We are being rate limited. Retrying in 3.54 seconds. Handled under the bucket "724975725488373823:None:/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}"`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How many messages did you try to delete? Max. 100 per command is recommended.

Comment: i tried to delete 20 messages but even if i delete 10 it still gets ratelimited

Comment: Then something else in your code has to cause the error. I was testing your code and never got ratelimited, even if I spammed the command or wanted to delete 1000 messages. Have a look at other commands that could cause the ratelimit. (Also other commands that were used before can then have an effect/impact on other commands, in your case the `purge` command.)

Comment: How do you know that this command is the command getting you rate limited? I don't see any issue with the provided code, which leads me to believe there's something else wrong here

Comment: i only get ratelimited when i use this command.I dont know why

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use the `bulk=True` argument in the `purge` function. This asks discord to delete all the messages while sending only one request